# Wildcards in apache virtualhosts

Tags: apache, virtualhost, dnsmasq

I try to get my apache (2.4) routing all *.dev requests to the directory /var/www/vhosts/*.dev (softlink)

What i've done:

I created a dnsmasq configuration like this:

```
address=/dev/127.0.0.1
```

And i can ping to any *.dev url

```
PING something.dev (127.0.53.53) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.53.53): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.049 ms
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.53.53): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.072 ms
```

So i would say this is working. And the proble is in apache configuration. There is only one site enabled and the vhost_alias mod is also enabled.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/%0
VirtualScriptAlias /var/www/vhosts/%0
<Directory />
  Options FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride None
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/vhosts/>
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
  AllowOverride All
  Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I've created a directory  /var/www/vhosts/test.dev and I expected, that I can browse from the local machine to this url: test.dev

```
matthias@matthias-VirtualBox:~$ ls /var/www/vhosts/test.dev/
index.html
```

Edit:
This problem is strange. I can download the index.html with wget http://test.dev But I can't show the page in any browser (tested with chrome and firefox)
Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out, that .dev is a new tld. I had to change the order of dns in resolv.conf.